# Why is the URL undefined (After JQuery Ajax Post)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

So basically, I'm trying to refresh the view after I do an Ajax Post in a Profile View.

```
 $.ajax({ 
     url: '/Profile/Index',
     dataType: "html", 
     type: "POST", 
     data: JSON.stringify(10), 
     success: function(returl) { 
         alert('It worked'); 
         window.location.href = returl.url;
     }, 
     error: function(jqXHR,responseText,textStatus) {
         alert(jqXHR.responseText) 
     } 
});
```

This is the HttpPost Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string number){
    //Things to do
    var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Profile");
    return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl });
}
```

And after the post is made I get this URL: http://localhost:50738/undefined
I already debugged the Controller method and it gets /Profile correctly. I can't understand why this problem keeps going... Thanks!

Comment: What does `console.log(returl)` print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're telling the Ajax request to expect HTML to be returned and not JSON, so returl will quite literally be a string value and thus returl.url will be undefined. Change your datatype to json instead.

Found this on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings. Look at the datatype parameter for more info.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Profile/Index',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(10),
        success: function (returl) {
            alert('It worked');
            window.location.href = returl.Url;
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, responseText, textStatus) {
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Changed datatype to JSON, but I still get the same error :s

Comment: Like @galactocalypse also pointed out, the case of url is incorrect and should be Url instead. See revised ajax in my answer above

Comment: Oh right, Forget it, forget it, it's because of the small "u" it didn't work. Thanks xD

Answer (score 2):

If you are returning just a single string, return it as it is

**Controller Code**

```
return Json(redirectUrl);
```

and directly use the string in response

```
$.ajax({
url: '/Profile/Index',
dataType: "json",
type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(10),
        success: function (returl) {
            alert('It worked');
            window.location.href = returl;
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, responseText, textStatus) {
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: True, but not as flexible going forward. +1 for avoiding the case-sensitive bug anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `location.href=returl.Url` instead of `location.href=returl.url`. Also fix the expected type to 'json' as the above answer points out.

Comment: What about `console.log(returl)`?

Comment: Forget it, forget it, it's because of the small "u" it didn't work. Thanks xD

Comment: So how was it still undefined even when you changed the case?